# security:global-method-security element in spring security configuration?

Tags: spring-security

What is the use of security:global-method-security element in spring security configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-global-method)?